# How to reject an EULA when installing packages with apt?

Tags: installation, apt, command-line, license

I wanted to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` with apt, but they include `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, for which I must accept an EULA license. I don’t want to, but I can't find a way to reject it. There is an 'OK' button but no 'Reject'.

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but it only makes the installer blink and show the license again.

Closing the terminal or killing the process is not an option because the file lock doesn't get freed.

Comment: Note if you reject the EULA you cannot install that software, and if that package is required by another package, you can't install that package because the dependencies are then broken.

Comment: Yep, i know that. I just want to end the installation of the ubuntu-restricted-extras and install only it's dependencies that i want avoiding ttf-mscorefonts-installer. But more generally, just how to reject eula, i don't care (in fact i expect) that the installation of the new packages get rolled back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to hit OK, then it will present you another screen asking if you accept the EULA. This second screen takes a Yes/No response.

Comment: Thanks, once you it’s easy but i don't think it's intuitive. Thanks again.

Comment: File a bug report on the package. I belive that you will help improve the package with that.

Comment: Kind of exasperating that two years later this is still an issue, but ... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1283746

Answer (score 1):

You could download the package then delete the portion of it you don't want.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but... Signing a EULA and then removing the software is not necessarily the same as not signing it in the first place. Some terms of the agreement may survive termination of the "contract." If you don't want to sign a EULA, signing it and then deleting the software is an undesirable workaround at best.

Comment: I know you still accept, but you are getting rid of the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. This is the package they didn't want. And wouldn't deleting the package make that portion relating to the EULA null/void due to a lack of that file?

Comment: *For this particular package*, deleting all the font files (which should happen when you remove the package) should terminate [any obligations under the license](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/msttcorefonts/precise/view/head:/debian/templates). (But I am **not a laywer** and this is **not legal advice**.) For EULAs in general though, including some that might be accepted through APT, this is not the case--you can have obligations or restrictions that survive termination of the contract. *It's best not to agree to something if you don't agree to it.*

Comment: I'm not a lawyer either, but I think anything signed under duress is invalid. If clicking "I accept" is the only way to get at ANOTHER package, this is clearly an abusive clause. Anyway I don't need their fonts and I'll do what I want with anything that comes on my computer.