# how can we prevent ttf-mscorefonts-installer to be installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, fonts

When i try to install some packages after a fresh-install, ttf-mscorefonts-install appears as dependency, and is trying to force me to agree with Microsoft’s licence, which i don’t agree at all.

So i edited /etc/apt/preferences, and added "Pin-Priority: -1" to this package, and then, when using "sudo apt-get install (whateverpackage)", it keeps insisting "E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can’t find an archive for it".

So, how can i fix this, since i'll never agree with that eula licence? is the only solution trying to create a dummy package via Alien, and lock that on Synaptic? Or is there any easier way?

Comment: Simply don't install packages that require it... find the incriminated packages that need these fonts and avoid installing them

Comment: See this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425085/did-i-accept-the-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-eula - you can't prevent it to be installed if another package has it as a dependency but you can prevent it to install those fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Run `apt-get download package` to download .deb without installation. Open it with archiever and edit the dependencies to throw away what you don't like. Then install the edited package with `dpkg -i package.deb`. Then run `apt-get install -f` to install other dependencies.