# Why are fonts being substituted in Libreoffice even if they are installed?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I am very sure `Arial` is installed on my computer, because when I type `fc-match Arial` I see `LiberationSans-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Regular"` as the output in the terminal.

However all the fonts in my LibreOffice Calc look horrible. As I hover over "Arial" in the fonts, I see "Font Name". The current font is not available and will be substituted`.

Why is this happening? How to stop this?

Comment: How did you install Arial?

Comment: I looked for Arial on Software-Center. I found one package called `tts-mscorefonts-installer`. I clicked on install. It did flash me that some EULA wasn't signed or something. But the installations completed.

Comment: If the EULA wasn't signed, then it's unlikely the fonts were installed - those are downloaded separately by the package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did I accept the ttf-mscorefonts-installer EULA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425085/did-i-accept-the-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-eula)

Comment: What is the output of `fc-list 'Arial'`?

Answer (score 2):

If `fc-match` suggests you a font which is not the one you requested, it means the font is **not** installed.

To install it, type this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

That will reinstall the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. Make sure you accept the license otherwise it will again not install the font.

Comment: No, the question says that Arial is definitely installed **because** the computer says it isn't using the font. That's not valid reasoning. I definitely didn't have the Arial font, and `fc-match Arial` gave me the exact same response as in the question. The comments to the question say that the EULA wasn't accepted, which prevents the font from being installed. After installing the package and accepting the EULA, `fc-match Arial` says `Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Regular"`, so this is an answer that works.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex not necessarily this command runs actually on 16.04 into emptiness with a half installed package which is missing fonts.

Comment: It cannot be inferred that OP missing the font just from `fc-match`'s output. Because `fc-match` doesn't list the font, instead it shows the best matching font, which you can control. Even if you have Arial font, it can show "Liberation Sans". @ChaiT.Rex

Comment: It can be inferred from "It did flash me that some EULA wasn't signed or something." The package won't install the fonts without the EULA being signed.

Comment: I apologize for the first comment. I actually wanted to put emphasis on the fact that You can't rely on `fc-match`'s output and I have the same situation today. I have arial and fc-match shows Liberation Sans

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments on the other answer here, you have in fact no Arial font installed other wise `fc-match Arial` would state the following:

```
$ fc-match Arial
Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Regular"
```

> Edit: as @Anwar stated in comment `fc-match` can yield a false result,
>   so to be sure do as well an `fc-list Arial` which should yield an output
>   like the following:

```
$ fc-list Arial
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
```

So to make sure it is really properly installed (the usual command runs sadly in 404 errors during installation) do the following:

```
apt remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This removes the current installation. Just doing this to make sure we accept the EULA in the next following installation dialog.

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

It most likely gives you while installing a few error messages while installation, stating that it can't fetch the font from sourceforge.net.
To work around this simply do the following:

```
TMP=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$TMP"
awk '/Url/ {system("wget "$2)}' /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts "$TMP"/*
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This is should result in a fairly long output processing all the Microsoft fonts and updating them. All now needed to do is cleaning up.

```
cd ..
rm -r "$TMP"
```

To test now do an `fc-match Arial` again which should now yield the above stated result.

Comment: `fc-match Arial` will not always show the font even if the font is installed. It's not a 100% surety test.  Instead `fc-list Arial` should be used